# Scrolling to the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, scroll, scrollto

I'm struggling with a jquery or javascript problem.

It already got annoying which tells me I might think too complicated on this one.

**So my markup (simplyfied) looks like this:**

```
<div class="container">
    My Content
<a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container">
    My Content
<a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container">
    My Content
<a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container">
    My Content
<a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>
```

Basically just some containers.

Each one contains different content and a button.

---

**The Plan:**

1) After a click on a button the window should scroll down to the **next container**.

2) The last button **scrolls to the first** container again. So I need a **loop**.

3) The **numbers** of containers may change from page to page.

**EDIT:** 4) The containers may not always be direct siblings to each other (see markup below)

---

**The Problem:**

I could get this to work by giving each container a unique ID as a target for the scroll effect.

The problem with that is that it gets too messy quickly.

Cant I just somehow target "*the next object with the class: container*", and scroll to that?

---

I'm not sure if js or jquery is the right approach. My knowledge in both is somewhat limited.

**I would be really grateful for a push in the right direction.**

---

**EDIT:** The containers may not always be direct siblings of each other.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>
</div>        

        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            My Content
        <a href="#" class="button">scroll down</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Simple solution:

To get the next container, try using [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Basically, the `<div>` containers are siblings of each other, so calling `.next()` on one div container will give you the next.

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
    $(document).scrollTop($(this).parent().next().offset().top);
    // $(this).parent().next() // this is the next div container.
    return false; // prevent anchor
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/1/)

You just use `$(this)` to get the link object, `.parent()` to get the parent of the link, which is the `<div>`, then `.next()` to get the next sibling (note it will wrap automatically, so the sibling after the last `<div>` is the **first** `<div>!),`.offset()`to get its position relative to the page,`.top` to get it relative to the top border.

Then you just use `$(document).scrollTop()` to scroll to that location.

---

### For a completely general solution, use:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
    container = $(this).parent();

    // if I am the last .container in my group...
    while (    document != container[0] // not reached root
            && container.find('~.container, ~:has(.container)').length == 0)
        container = container.parent(); // search siblings of parent instead

    nextdiv = container.nextAll('.container, :has(.container)').first();

    // no next .container found, go back to first container
    if (nextdiv.length==0) nextdiv = $(document).find('.container:first');

    $(document).scrollTop(nextdiv.offset().top);
    // $(this).parent().next() // this is the next div container.
    return false;
});
```

​The code basically uses `container.find('~.container, ~:has(.container)')` to find any sibling that has or is a `.container`. If nothing, then go up the DOM tree 1 step.

After it finds something which is or has a `.container`, it grabs it with `nextdiv = container.nextAll('.container, :has(.container)').first();`.

Lastly, if nothing is found, checked by `nextdiv.length==0`, just grab the first `.container` in the whole page.

Then scroll to whatever `.container` was grabbed.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/3/)

---

To animate the scroll, place the `scrollTop` property in an `animate` function:

```
// $(document).scrollTop(nextdiv.offset().top); // snaps to new scroll position
$('body').animate({scrollTop:nextdiv.offset().top},300); // animates scrolling
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/4/)

Comment: Hi ronalchn, thank you for your answer. Interesting approach. Unfortunately Im afraid I oversimplified my markup to present it here, because the containers are not always direct siblings of each other. I've updated the question accordingly. 
Sorry for the trouble, I simply wasn't aware that this might cause problems. Thanks a ton for your efforts!

Comment: Added general solution (adds 3 statements) - it is even more general than the structure you added to your solution, it will work with any page structure!

Comment: Hey ronalch,
Wow! Amazing, thank you for your help. I will implement it tomorrow but looks like its working neatly. Its only a little confusing if you dont have a scrolling animation. I thought about using .animate() for this but I'm not sure where to put it without messing up your script. Is that possible? Thanks a ton! Very impressive!

Comment: just have to modify the line doing the scrolling, and put the property into an `animate` function, as shown above.

Comment: Hi ronalchn! Worked absolutely perfect! Absolutely impressive! Thank you very much!!! Oh and I really apreciated the "//comments". Helped me a lot with my understanding. Out of curiosity: How long did it take you to learn all that?

Comment: I don't remember **all** the functions, I just know what can be done, and what kind of functions might be used. So I just do some quick searches on the things I don't know or remember.

Comment: Hi @ronalchn ! Just a quick followup question: How would you add a little margin of say 5px to the top-edge of the window? (so the container have some spacing between their top-edge and the top-edge of the screen, after the scrolling) Is there a jquery trick I should look at? Thanks once more. Can hardly tell you hom much you helped me! :-)

Comment: if you want a margin on the page, look at `<body style="top-margin: 4px"`

Comment: Brilliant! Carefully crafted answer. I am studying a page from a site created by a british high-street web agency and I got here by googling one of the comments in the code: your JS sample has been taken and reused as-is ;-)
Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery...

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript is not required for this. You can use HTML anchors.

```
<div class="container" id="first">
    My Content
<a href="#second" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container" id="second">
    My Content
<a href="#third" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container" id="third">
    My Content
<a href="#fourth" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>


<div class="container" id="fourth">
    My Content
<a href="#first" class="button">scroll down</a>
</div>
```

Comment: _I could get this to work by giving each container a unique ID as a target for the scroll effect. The problem with that is that it gets too messy quickly._

Answer (score -2):

What you want can be easily achieved through `parent()` and `child()`.

If the number of containers on each page is different, then you should start ID'ing (don't know if that's a term) containers serially. Something like, `class="container-1"`

The click event on the last button should do something like:

```
var num = $('div[class^="container-"]').filter(function() {
    return((" " + this.className + " ").match(/\scontainer-\d+\s/) != null);
});
num++;
var last_container = $(this).parent('.container' + num);
last_container .scrollTo();
```

Am sure you can figure out what the next button should do  ;)