# On click page scroll works in FF, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a vertical navigation click function on my site that is working just fine in Firefox and IE10 and IE9, but doesn't work in Chrome or Safari. I'm not getting any chrome errors when inspecting the page.

The original code I got this from works in FF and Chrome, but since I've forked it, the code doesn't function any more in Chrome.

Original Code: 
[Scrolling to the next element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329008/scrolling-to-the-next-element/12329014#12329014)

Original jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pm3cj/3/

My Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjb6631d/1/

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 5000px">

<section class="cover" style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <section class="controls">
        <p class="prev">prev</p>
        <p class="next">next</p>
        1
    </section>      
</section>

<section class="cover" style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <section class="controls">
        <p class="prev">prev</p>
        <p class="next">next</p>
        2
    </section>      
</section>

<section class="cover" style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <section class="controls">
        <p class="prev">prev</p>
        <p class="next">next</p>
        3
    </section>      
</section>

</div>
```

Script:

```
    $('.cover:first').addClass('first-child');
    $('.cover:last').addClass('last-child');
    $(".next, .prev").on("click", function(e) {

    // the container that will be scrolled to
    var target = '.cover';
    container = $(this).parent();

    // am I the last .container in my group?
    while (document != container[0] && container.find('~'+target, '~:has('+target+')').length == 0)
        container = container.parent(); // if so, search siblings of parent instead

    prevdiv = container.prevAll(target, ':has('+target+')').first();
    nextdiv = container.nextAll(target, ':has('+target+')').first();

    // if clicked next object
    if ( $(this).hasClass('next') ) {
        // no next .container found, go back to first container
        if (nextdiv.length==0) nextdiv = $(document).find(target+':first');

        //$(document).scrollTop(nextdiv.offset().top);
        $('html').animate({scrollTop:nextdiv.offset().top},300);        
    }

    // if clicked prev
    if ( $(this).hasClass('prev') ) {
        // no next .container found, go back to first container

        // scroll to previous element
        prevdiv = $(this).parents(target).prev(target);

        // if is first element on page, then scroll to last element
        if ( $(this).parents(target).hasClass('first-child') ) {
            prevdiv =  $(document).find(target+':last');
        };      

        //$(document).scrollTop(nextdiv.offset().top);
        $('html').animate({scrollTop:prevdiv.offset().top},300);        
    }

    // $(this).parent().next() // this is the next div container.
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that in Chrome (for some reason) it is not possible to scroll using

```
$('html').animate({scrollTop:....
```

Instead you have to use

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop:....
```

In Firefox and IE on the other hand it's just the other way around. So i would suggest you use

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:....
```

to make it work in all the browsers

EDIT: The difference between your reference and your code is, that in the reference, the `jQuery` function `$(document).scrollTop` is used, which takes the compatibility part off your shoulders, which `animate({scrollTop})` can't

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I knew the issue was something small - it always is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the animate function. Add "body" to the selector:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:nextdiv.offset().top},300);
```

and:
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:prevdiv.offset().top},300);

Tested in Chrome. Reference: http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery